# Share Kit, can't get keyboard up in twitter auth web view

Tags: ios4, keyboard, sharekit

Trying to use share kit to send a link to twitter,and when the webview comes up to log into twitter, you can tap into the username and password fields, get a cursor, but no keyboard pops up.

This is really starting to frustrate me.

Here's how I'm trying to call Share kit. (from an alert)

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (alertView.tag == 21){
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        //call SHK
        NSLog(@"Calling SHK");


        // Create the item to share (in this example, a url)
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://link.com"];
        SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just played a %d by %d board on #GAMENAME and solved it in %d moves!", down, across, turns]];



        // Get the ShareKit action sheet
        [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];

        SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

        // Display the action sheet
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with UIResponder

[UIResponder Troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581395/uiresponder-troubles)