# UIResponder Troubles

Tags: ios4, keyboard, uiresponder

Tonight I've been battling with UIResponder. Here's my predicament.

If I put in

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return YES;
}
```

to my mainViewController then I can get shake events..

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
         //do something 
    }
}
```

However, this means that when I call things like mail forms and webviews, the keyboard does not show up.

Is there any way I can get both shakes working and keyboard working in modal views?

I've tried adding     [self resignFirstResponder];
in -viewDidDissapear, which gets called when a modal pops over, but no luck.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with iOS < 5.0, shake event and showing a mail form. You have to resign the first responder before the new modal view controller is being presented.

Comment: I've tried adding [self resignFirstResponder]; in -viewDidDissapear, which gets called when a modal pops over, but no luck.

Comment: Seems viewDidDissapear is too late! Good to know. Horrible to know at the same time.